# ASP.NET Core: Prevent Automatic HTTP 400 responses for individual action

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-core

I like the [Automatic HTTP 400 responses](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/web-api/?view=aspnetcore-2.1#automatic-http-400-responses) functionality new to ASP.NET Core 2.1 and it's working out really well for most cases.

However, in one action I need to do a bit of pre-processing before validation the payload. I have a custom validator that requires two values in the model to perform validation. One of those values is in the path so I would like to set that value on the model from the path then validate.

I don't want to switch the functionality off for all actions with:

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.Configure<ApiBehaviorOptions>(options =>
    {
        options.SuppressModelStateInvalidFilter = true;
    });
}
```

Is there any way I could switch it off just for an individual action?

**Edit:**

I tried modifying the InvalidModelStateResponseFactory but it didn't solve my problem because I still need to get into the controller action:

```
services.Configure<ApiBehaviorOptions>(options =>
{
    options.InvalidModelStateResponseFactory = actionContext =>
    {
        var ignore = actionContext.ActionDescriptor.FilterDescriptors.Any(fd => fd.Filter is SuppressModelStateInvalidFilterAttribute);
        if (ignore)
        {
            // Can only return IActionResult so doesn't enter the controller action.
        }

        return new BadRequestObjectResult(actionContext.ModelState);
    };
});

[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Method)]
public class SuppressModelStateInvalidFilterAttribute : FormatFilterAttribute
{
}
```

**Edit:**

Here's a link to an issue I raised on the asp.net core repo in case I get anywhere with that - https://github.com/aspnet/Mvc/issues/8575

Comment: Well, if you are okay with adding a 3rd party library, there is a tool called fluent validation which helps in validating complex model types, and also supports "pre-validation" logic. It might help. Here is the docs: https://fluentvalidation.net/start#using-prevalidate

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This could probably be solved by implementing your own validator for your specific case. It is covered quite well in the documentation.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/models/validation?view=aspnetcore-2.1#custom-validation

Either that or possibly a custom model binder to create your model with all the preprocessing done before it is validated.

Comment: I am implementing a custom validator. I just need to get a value from the path and set it on the model before validating. I think your custom binder suggestion may be the way to go. I'll try that. Thanks.

Answer (score 12):

**Update:** you can just use the following code in ConfigureServices in Startup.cs:

```
services.Configure<ApiBehaviorOptions>(apiBehaviorOptions => {
    apiBehaviorOptions.SuppressModelStateInvalidFilter = true;
});
```

---

Based on Simon Vane's answer, I had to modify the attribute for ASP.Net Core 2.2 as follows:

```
/// <summary>
/// Suppresses the default ApiController behaviour of automatically creating error 400 responses
/// </summary>
[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Method)]
public class SuppressModelStateInvalidFilterAttribute : Attribute, IActionModelConvention {
    private static readonly Type ModelStateInvalidFilterFactory = typeof(ModelStateInvalidFilter).Assembly.GetType("Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ModelStateInvalidFilterFactory");

    public void Apply(ActionModel action) {
        for (var i = 0; i < action.Filters.Count; i++) {
            if (action.Filters[i] is ModelStateInvalidFilter || action.Filters[i].GetType() == ModelStateInvalidFilterFactory) {
                action.Filters.RemoveAt(i);
                break;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5):

I had a response from Microsoft - https://github.com/aspnet/Mvc/issues/8575

The following worked a charm.

```
[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Method)]
public class SuppressModelStateInvalidFilterAttribute : Attribute, IActionModelConvention
{
    public void Apply(ActionModel action)
    {
        for (var i = 0; i < action.Filters.Count; i++)
        {
            if (action.Filters[i] is ModelStateInvalidFilter)
            {
                action.Filters.RemoveAt(i);
                break;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

In my controller I could then make changes to the model before re-validating it (note the ModelState.Clear(), TryValidateModel add to existing model state):

```
if (model == null)
{
    return BadRequest(ModelState);
}

model.Property = valueFromPath;

ModelState.Clear();
if (TryValidateModel(model) == false)
{
    return BadRequest(ModelState);
}
```

Comment: It should be action.Filters[i] is ModelStateInvalidFilterFactory but it is internal ;/.

Answer (score 2):

You could play with [`ApiBehaviorOptions.InvalidModelStateResponseFactory`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.mvc.apibehavioroptions.invalidmodelstateresponsefactory) property to handle specific cases based on `actionContext` details:

```
services.Configure<ApiBehaviorOptions>(options =>
{
    options.InvalidModelStateResponseFactory = actionContext => 
    {
        // Do what you need here for specific cases with `actionContext` 
        // I believe you can cehck the action attributes 
        // if you'd like to make mark / handle specific cases by action attributes. 

        return new BadRequestObjectResult(context.ModelState);
    }
});
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for these suggestion I had high hopes for this but it doesn't solve my problem. I need to get into the controller action. Just for a bit of extra info for what you can do, I've added an update to my question.

Answer (score 2):

I encountered similar problem and came up with this solution.

```
public class SuppressModelStateInvalidFilterAttribute : ActionFilterAttribute
{
    public SuppressModelStateInvalidFilterAttribute()
    {
        Order = -2500;
    }

    public override Task OnActionExecutionAsync(ActionExecutingContext context, ActionExecutionDelegate next)
    {
        context.ModelState.Clear();
        return next.Invoke();
    }
}
```