# Whay cannot hit the breakpoint in Controller when ModelState.IsValid is false?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core

my class model had schema required

```
public partial class AuthorModel
{
    public string AuthorId { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public string AuthorName { get; set; }
}
```

Why if ModelState.IsValid has error or false, breakpoint is not hitting the Get Function?

```
public class AuthorController : Controller
{
    [HttpPost]
    public IActionResult Get(AuthorModel authors)
    {
        //if ModelState.IsValid has error, breakpoint is not hitting here?? 
        //Only hitting this function when ModelState.IsValid is true/
        //I used [Required schema] for AuthorModel.AuthorName
        if (!ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            return BadRequest(error: new { ErrorCode = "01010101", ErrorMessage = "sample message" });
        }
        using (var context = new BookStoreContext())
        {
            return null;
        }
    }
  }
```

it's auto display error message result,

[image]

I want to Customized the error message before it's display.

Comment: please post code, error messages, or any other basically textual information ***as text, not as screenshot***. thanks.

Comment: The validation filters are action guards.If guarantees that action is not executed if the model is not valid so that you no need to check if model is valid again in action.

Comment: With `ApiControllerAttribute`, ASP.NET Core return automatically 400 response when the model isn't valid. See the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/web-api/?view=aspnetcore-5.0#automatic-http-400-responses) for more information.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

ASP.Net Core has a default `ModelStateInvalidFilter` which, being a filter, is being executed before the controller method is executed. When the `ModelState.Valid == false` none of your code in the controller will be executed. However, you can suppress the filter:

**Startup.cs**

```c#
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.Configure<ApiBehaviorOptions>(options =>
    {
        options.SuppressModelStateInvalidFilter = true;
    });
}
```

Keep in mind that this disables the filter globally. If you want to be able to disable it for specific actions, see https://stackoverflow.com/a/56350823/12431728

Which suggests a custom filter which looks like this:

```c#
/// <summary>
/// Suppresses the default ApiController behaviour of automatically creating error 400 responses
/// </summary>
[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Method)]
public class SuppressModelStateInvalidFilterAttribute : Attribute, IActionModelConvention {
    private static readonly Type ModelStateInvalidFilterFactory = typeof(ModelStateInvalidFilter).Assembly.GetType("Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ModelStateInvalidFilterFactory");

    public void Apply(ActionModel action) {
        for (var i = 0; i < action.Filters.Count; i++) {
            if (action.Filters[i] is ModelStateInvalidFilter || action.Filters[i].GetType() == ModelStateInvalidFilterFactory) {
                action.Filters.RemoveAt(i);
                break;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

To use the filter just add `[SuppressModelStateInvalidFilter]` above the desired controller action method.

Answer (score 0):

Customize error message:

```
public partial class AuthorModel
{
    public string AuthorId { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "your message")]
    public string AuthorName { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but the issue is I want to customize the message in Controller for another reason.

Answer (score 0):

To customize error messages you can provide those to attributes for example:

```
[Required(ErrorMessage = "Some error message")]
public string AuthorName { get; set; }
```

or

```
[Required(ErrorMessageResourceType = typeof(ValidationMessages), ErrorMessageResourceName = "AuthorName ")]
public string AuthorName { get; set; }
```

Regarding not hitting when IsValid is false, I haven't worked recently with asp.net but it looks like that some ActionFilter (default or custom) is applied and actions is not hit when model state is invalid and returns validation error to a client.

Comment: Thanks, but the issue is I want to customize the message in Controller for another reason.

Comment: do you apply some validation filter?